# JavaScript funcão 1 esperar retorno da função 2 (sync await promise.all)

Tags: javascript, assincronismo

Estou com uma dúvida muito grande em relação a utilização de `async/await` e também de `Promise.all`.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
class Conexao {
  constructor(loading) {
  this.loading = loading;
}

acessar(rota) {
  return this.requisicao(rota, 1);
}


async requisicao(rota, id) {
  let rotas = ['https://willianjusten.com.br/search.json']
  rotas.push(rota);

  await Promise.all(rotas.map(function(url) {
    fetch(url).then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json();
    }).then(function(r) {
      return r;
    })
  }));
 }
}

let conn = new Conexao(true);
let result_final = 
conn.acessar('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/');
console.log(result_final);
```

Como eu faria pra ao chamar a função acessar, aguardar o retorno da função requisição e após o retorno estiver concluido, a variavel `result_final` mostrar o que retornou?

Estou tentando dessa forma como mostrei acima, porém ou me retorna `undefined` ou `[object promise]`.

Não tem como "dizer" pra funcão acessar(rota):

- *"Ei, espera a função requisicao resolver tudo que ela vai te dar uma resposta e dai sim vc manda pra `result_final`?*

A melhor forma que encontrei de explicar...

Alguém poderia me ajudar e me explicar o que estou fazendo de errado?

O código está no jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/dowitobolu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então jovem, vamos lá. As funções `async` por definição retornam uma `Promise`, se você retornar apenas um valor, tipo o código abaixo, o Js circunda o valor com uma Promise.

```
async function f1() {
  return 'f1';
}

let v1 = f1();

console.log(v1); // Prints Promise { 'f1' }

f1().then(v => {
  console.log(v); // Prints 'f1'
});
```

Não tem muito como fugir disso, isso ocorre para que funções `async` não congelem a execução do script, visto que elas são assíncronas, enquanto elas estão paradas esperando a resolução de uma Promise.

A vantagem das funções async é que internamente você pode congelar a execução esperando a resolução de uma Promise usando a keyword `await`. Para ter acesso ao retorno de uma função async você vai precisar **sempre** usar o `.then()`, isso é em certo ponto uma proteção e garantia do tipo de retorno das funções assíncronas (eu sei que "garantia e protração" não são coisas muito usuais em Js). Se funções assíncronas encapsulassem o retorno sempre, isso geraria bastante dor de cabeça, vários códigos quebrariam enquanto tentam chamar o método `then` de um inteiro, o que seria bem frustrante.

**Como resolver o seu problema?**

Usando o famoso `then`:

```
let conn = new Conexao(true);
let result_final = conn.acessar('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/');
result_final.then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Ahh.. Agora sim entendi certinho.

Comment: Por exemplo... Eu ja resolver ela assim que retorna pra função acessar com o then e somente apos a resolução devolver pra variavel result_final infelizmente nao tem como né?  Cara, sério.. Eu quebrei a cabeça com isso desde ontem.. Muito orbigado mesmo a todos!

Comment: Tipo, você não consegue garantir que o resultado estará disponível fora do callback do `then`... Você só vai conseguir usar ele lá dentro

Answer (score 1):

Como é executado async, vc precisa aguardar a execução usando o then.
Algo assim:

```
let conn = new Conexao(true);
conn.acessar('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
.then((result_final) => {
      console.log(result_final);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A única coisa que tens de mudar é a ultima linha, pois `result_final` é uma promise e podes usar o `then` para consumir o valor que ela retorna quando a promise tiver completado a parte assíncrona.

```
result_final.then(res => console.log(res));
```

```js
class Conexao {
  constructor(loading) {
    this.loading = loading;
  }

  acessar(rota) {
    return this.requisicao(rota, 1);
  }

  async requisicao(rota, id) {

    let rotas = ['https://willianjusten.com.br/search.json']
    rotas.push(rota);

    // aqui eu crio a lista de Promises
    const promises = rotas.map(url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json()));

    // aqui eu espero a resposta de todas as promises direitinho
    const response = await Promise.all(promises);

    // aí respondo
    if(response) {
      return response;
    }

  }
}

let conn = new Conexao(true);
let result_final = conn.acessar('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/');
result_final.then(res => console.log(res));
```